# POST null because property type does not match?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a asp .net core API with simple REST methods like this:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody] ItemClass newItem)
    {
        [...]
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The model class is pretty simple as well:

```cs
public class ItemClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

When I POST this JSON to the service

```json
{
    "id": null,
    "name": "Some name",
    "description": "Some description",
    "isActive": null
}
```

the method is called with `newItem` set to `null`. No error, no exception, the the object was just `null`. It took me quite a while to figure out the parameter `isActive` was the cause of the problem. In the class I defined it as `bool`, but JSON defined it as `null`. When I either change the value to `true` or `false` or when I leave it out completely or when I change the parameter to `bool?` it works again. The object is deserialized correctly.

I'm used to asp net core APIs to be very resilient. Usually when a parameter is simply set to its default when it can not be parsed correctly from the message.
But why does the whole object become `null` here?
Is there at least a way to tell asp net core to throw an exception when the deserialization fails?

Comment: Previous versions used a 3rd party JSON parser (JSON.net) that was more stable and flexible. Current versions are using inhouse JSON parser (System.Text.Json) that is still rough around the edges.

Comment: I think it is good that the whole object is null. Other wise you will get IsActive as false(by default)  in your action, but it will be a wrong result.

Comment: It seems that since the data scheme does not match the properties absolutely, the data is not bound to the input object. Anyway, it is possible to configure [custom formatters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-5.0#how-to-configure-mvc-to-use-a-custom-formatter)

Comment: if you change your action to this -   Insert([FromBody] string Id, string Name,...bool? IsActive=null) it will work as you like.

Comment: @dante, can you share the api version?

Comment: @Karney Sorry for the late reply. I'm using .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When null is mapped to the bool, resulting in a type mismatch exception, it will cause the whole object become null.

If this api is 3.x, it will trigger 400. But in 2.x and 5.0, they have no exception. You can handle the null value through NewtonSoft.json.

A simple way to handel it with this configuration, it can assign a default value to bool, but it doesn't trigger exception.

In 2.x

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options=>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

5.0

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(option=>
            {
                option.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

[image]

If must return an error, you have to use a custom model binding.

```
public class CustomBindClassBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {

        var itemClass = new ItemClass();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
        {
            var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            var mydata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(body.Result);

            if(mydata["isActive"].ToString()==""|| mydata["isActive"].ToString() == null)
            {
                bindingContext.Result= ModelBindingResult.Failed();
                throw new Exception("isActive is not correct");
            }
            else
            {
                itemClass.Id = mydata["id"].ToString();
                itemClass.Name = mydata["name"].ToString();
                itemClass.Description = mydata["description"].ToString();
                itemClass.IsActive = bool.Parse(mydata["isActive"].ToString());
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(itemClass);
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

In action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Insert([FromBody][ModelBinder(typeof(CustomBindClassBinder))] ItemClass newItem)
    {
        
        return Ok(newItem);
    }
```