# How to make ASP.NET Core bind partially to valid data?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Let's say I have this model:

```
public enum State
{
    Valid = 1,
    Invalid = 2
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    
    public State state { get; set; }
}
```

And this controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public object SavePerson([FromBody] Person person)
{
    return person;
}
```

If I send this JSON, everything works just fine:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "state": 1
}
```

However, if I change the `"state": 1` to an invalid enumeration like `"state": ""` or `"state": "1"`, then the `person` parameter would be null.

In other words, if I send a JSON that is **partially** valid, ASP.NET Core ignores all fields.

How can I configure ASP.NET Core to at least extract the valid fields from the body?

Comment: you may refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65624020

Comment: Does this answer your question? [POST null because property type does not match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611565/post-null-because-property-type-does-not-match)

Comment: @wei, that is `Newtonsoft.Json`. We're using `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: seems like `System.Text.Json` doesn't have error handler. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/38049, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44390

Comment: `System.Text.Json` may not do what you want. You can use `Newtonsoft.Json` or try a [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/custom-formatters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#how-to-configure-mvc-to-use-a-custom-formatter).

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle deserialization exception.

This code will put a default value each time it will encounter a problem in a field but the json string itself must be a valid json string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This should be run on startup code (there are other ways to do that as well - you can put this settings only on controllers etc...)
        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Error = HandleDeserializationError
        };

        var jsonStr = "{\"name\": \"John\",\"state\": \"\" }";
        var person = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(jsonStr);         

        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person)); //{"Name":"John","state":0}
    }

    public static void HandleDeserializationError(object sender, ErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        var error = args.ErrorContext.Error.Message;
        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
    }
```

For WebAPI you should have a Startup.cs file looks like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //look for services.AddControllers() -> or add it if it does not exist
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddMvcOptions(options =>
            {
               //... might have options here
            })
               //this is what you need to add
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.Error = HandleDeserializationError
            });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please explain how can I handle this in ASP.NET Core pipeline? Because I already knew that I had to handle it myself somewhere. I don't know **where**?

Comment: @AliEXE see edit - if it is a webAPI .net core app

Comment: Awesome. Yet we do not use `Newtonsoft.Json`. We use `System.Text.Json`. Thank you for helping us.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nullable operator:

```
public State? state { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But this is not what I'm searching for. I don't want to change all of my models forcefully. I prefer to configure ASP.NET Core.